# Python : Get features of several images

Tags: python, image, feature-extraction

I would like to get the feature of a several images located in the same folder.

#### My codes are as follow - Prerequisites (librairies needed):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
import cv2
import os
```

#### Definition of folder where are located the images (around 6000)

```
images_dir = "TrainImages"
```

#### Creation of a function that defines the different variables et compute them

```
def get_data_from_image(image_path):
    cv_img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    (means, stds) = cv2.meanStdDev(cv_img)
    stats = np.concatenate([means, stds]).flatten()
    image_features_list = [stats.tolist()]
    return image_features_list
```

#### Creation of a variable that scans and analyses the images

```
image_files = [x.path for x in os.scandir(images_dir)]
```

#### Creation of a loop function

```
i = 0
mylist =[]

for i in range (4): # I test only 4 images, could be more
    mylist.append((get_data_from_image(image_files[i])))
```

#### Running the stuff

```
image_features_list = get_data_from_image(image_files[i])
```

#### Look at the output

```
image_features_list
```

#### The output provides **only the feature of one image**, **instead of all images** located in the folder

[Out]:

[[114.31548828125001,
139.148388671875,
139.57832682291667,
50.54138521536725,
53.82290182999255,
51.946187641459595]]

I would be grateful if I could have a solution on how to have the features of all images (not only one). At this effect, do not hesitate to correct the code.
Thanks and kindest regards

#### After some commments from friendly persons, here is an additional information for those who would be interested by the response : The output to look at is mylist.

```
mylist
```

[Out]:

[[[144.28788548752834,
151.28145691609978,
148.6195351473923,
51.50620316379085,
53.36979275398226,
52.2493589172815]],
[[56.220865079365076,
59.99653968253968,
60.28386507936508,
66.72797279655177,
65.24673515467009,
64.93141350917332]],
[[125.2066064453125,
118.1168994140625,
145.0827685546875,
68.95463582009148,
52.65138276425348,
56.68269683130363]],
[[114.31548828125001,
139.148388671875,
139.57832682291667,
50.54138521536725,
53.82290182999255,
51.946187641459595]]]

#### Thanks for your help.  It is a great forum here !

Comment: plz edit ur code sections

Comment: what do you see when you print **mylist**? and why the range of 4 while you have 6000 images?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question, I did a range of 4, just for test and see the results. I would certainly put more than 4 , to get all the image features.  Kindest regards

Comment: I have also edited the code section, to make it easier to read, thanks Cyrex for spotting that point.  Have a great day

Comment: Thanks Cyrex, actually, the output to look at is in mylist, indeed.  I do have all the features ....

Comment: Your code does not create a "loop function", it just calls the function in a loop, you just need to create a function that calls get_data_from_image in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach and tell me if its successful

```
import os, os.path
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2


def get_data_from_image(image_path):
    cv_img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    (means, stds) = cv2.meanStdDev(cv_img)
    stats = np.concatenate([means, stds]).flatten()
    image_features_list = [stats.tolist()]
    return image_features_list

images_dir = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Directory\\TrainImages\\'

images_names = []
 
with os.scandir(images_dir) as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        images_names.append(entry.name)


for image in images_names:

    path = images_dir + image

    image_features_list =  get_data_from_image(path))

    print(image_features_list)
```

Comment: Hi Cyrex, thats for trying.  I have the following error : error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-vu_aq9yd/opencv/modules/core/src/mean.dispatch.cpp:516: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'meanStdDev'

Comment: did u changed images_dir to your actual directory?

Comment: code updated, it should do exactly what its described. else, let me know if its not successful.